# JavaFX delay change of color in for loop

Tags: java, javafx

I have a grid pane that is filled with rectangles (4x4) and each rectangle needs to change color and needs to be done in a specific order with a delay between them. The order is given by the model in an array.

The presenter uses the array in a for loop which then tells the view to change the color of a block by index.

I've tried many things to add a delay so that they don't activate all at once but I can't seem to figure it out.

My for loop:

```
 int[][] grid = model.getGrid();

 for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            view.enableRegularBlock(i, j);
     }

 }
```

Things I've tried: **TimeLine:**

```
 public void enableRegularBlock(int i, int j) {
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
            Duration.millis(500),
            ae -> {
                Rectangle r = blockArray[i][j];
                r.setFill(activeColor);
                startTimer += 500;
            }));
    timeline.play();
 }
```

This is run inside the for loop, doesn't work as all rectangles activate at once.

**Thread:**

```
 int[][] grid = model.getGrid();

    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            final int row = i;
            final int col = j;
            Thread t = new Thread(){
               public void run() {
                   try{

                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                           @Override
                           public void run() {
                               view.enableRegularBlock(row, col);
                           }
                       });
                       Thread.sleep(500);
                   } catch(InterruptedException v){System.out.println(v);}
               }
           };

           t.start();

        }

    }
```

This also activates all rectangles at once.

Is there any way to add a delay between the rectangle activation that is also visible in the ui? So something like this: view.enableRegularBlock(0, 0) -> delay 500ms -> view.enableRegularBlock(0, 1) -> delay 500ms ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must not add the loop outside of the thread/event handler, ect.

Multiple timelines that are started from the loop run ***in parallel*** as do multiple threads.

Activate all the elements from a `Timeline` that runs multiple cycles:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    private int i = 0;
    private int j = 0;

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        Rectangle r = blockArray[i][j];
        r.setFill(activeColor);
        j++;
        if (j >= blockArray[i].length) {
            // "reset" inner loop, next step in outer loop
            j = 0;
            i++;
        }
    }
}));

// assuming same size of inner arrays here
timeline.setCycleCount(blockArray.length * blockArray[0].length);

timeline.play();
```

Or using a `Thread`:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            final Rectangle r = blockArray[i][j];

            Platform.runLater(() -> r.setFill(activeColor));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch(InterruptedException v){System.out.println(v);}
        }
    }
}).start();
```